# How to remove close timestamps?

Tags: r, time-series, timestamp

I have sensor data for several hours. The duration between timestamps scatters. The difference between timestamps should be around 0.5 seconds. Other rows with a higher or lower difference should be deleted. I would like to calculate the time difference to the previous existing timestamp.
In the following data frame rows 1,2,3,5 and 7 shall remain and rows 4 and 6 shall be deleted.

```
#       ax      ay     az           timestamp
# 1 0.0039  0.0005 1.0210 2018-06-03 19:40:00.00
# 2 0.0034  0.0303 1.0220 2018-06-03 19:40:00.50
# 3 0.0029  0.0361 1.0215 2018-06-03 19:40:01.00
# 4 0.0029  0.0430 1.0220 2018-06-03 19:40:01.20
# 5 0.0034  0.0679 1.0225 2018-06-03 19:40:01.50
# 6 0.0044  0.0645 1.0369 2018-06-03 19:40:01.90
# 7 0.0044 0.04684 1.0488 2018-06-03 19:40:02.00
```

If I calculate the difference between timestamps, I have a ciolumn for the difference.

```
df= mutate(df, difference_timestamp= as.numeric(difftime(timestamp,lag(timestamp), units = 'secs')))
```

The new data frame would look like this.

```
#       ax      ay     az           timestamp  difference_timestamp
# 1 0.0039  0.0005 1.0210 2018-06-03 19:40:00.00  NA
# 2 0.0034  0.0303 1.0220 2018-06-03 19:40:00.50  0.5
# 3 0.0029  0.0361 1.0215 2018-06-03 19:40:01.00  0.5
# 4 0.0029  0.0430 1.0220 2018-06-03 19:40:01.20  0.2
# 5 0.0034  0.0679 1.0225 2018-06-03 19:40:01.50  0.3
# 6 0.0044  0.0645 1.0369 2018-06-03 19:40:01.90  0.4
# 7 0.0044 0.04684 1.0488 2018-06-03 19:40:02.00  0.1
```

The difference to the previous timestamp can be seen. As the difference of row 4 to row 3 is less tahn 0.5, it is deleted. But if row 4 is deleted, the difference from row 5 to the last existing row, i.e. row 3, would be 0.5. Therefore, row 5 should be kept.
I tried it with `subset` and `lag`. But this approach delete rows and does not taking the last existing row into account, but the last row, even if it is deleted. So only rows 1,2 and 3 still exist.

```
subset(df, df$timestamp - dplyr::lag(df$timestamp) >= 0.49 & 
         df$timestamp - dplyr::lag(df$timestamp) <= 0.51)
```

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(ax = c("0.0039", "0.0034", "0.0029", "0.0029", 
"0.0034", "0.0044", "0.0044"), ay = c("0.0005", "0.0303", "0.0361", 
"0.0430", "0.0679", "0.0645", "0.04684"), az = c("1.0210", "1.0220", 
"1.0215", "1.0220", "1.0225", "1.0369", "1.0488"), timestamp = structure(c(1528047600, 
1528047600.5, 1528047601, 1528047601.2, 1528047601.5, 1528047601.9, 
1528047602), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Please include the data that is relevant to your question. There are only 2 columns in your sample data and your question mentions 7 columns. Even the column names are different.

Comment: This is just an simplified example. Therefore, there are two columns. In the question 7 rows are mentioned, not columns.

Comment: I updated the sample data

Comment: Posted code should be indented 4 spaces.  Do not preface code with > .

Answer (score 2):

You may use `diff` and look at the `abs`olute values.

```
subset(df, abs(c(0, diff(timestamp))) <= .5)
#       ax      ay     az           timestamp
# 1 0.0039  0.0005 1.0210 2018-06-03 19:40:00
# 2 0.0034  0.0303 1.0220 2018-06-03 19:40:00
# 3 0.0029  0.0361 1.0215 2018-06-03 19:40:01
# 5 0.0034  0.0679 1.0225 2018-06-03 19:40:02
# 7 0.0044 0.04684 1.0488 2018-06-03 19:40:02
```

Note, that I slightly changed your sample data to make sense out of it. Also note, that in `subset` another referencing of `df$` isn't needed.

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(ax = c("0.0039", "0.0034", "0.0029", "0.0029", 
"0.0034", "0.0044", "0.0044"), ay = c("0.0005", "0.0303", "0.0361", 
"0.0430", "0.0679", "0.0645", "0.04684"), az = c("1.0210", "1.0220", 
"1.0215", "1.0220", "1.0225", "1.0369", "1.0488"), timestamp = structure(c(1528047600, 
1528047600.5, 1528047601, 1528047602.2, 1528047602.5, 1528047601.9, 
1528047602), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: This works. Can you maybe explain briefly why it works for your data, but bot for mine approach. If I check, everything is the same data structure. Why does it not work on the actual data frame? Why you changed the class of the timestamp? Why you did 'subset(df, abs(c(.5, diff(timestamp))) <= .5)' and not 'subset(df, abs(diff(timestamp)) <= .5)'?  And why abs is important?

Comment: @mcfly Not entirely same data structure, I changed some miliseconds (not visible in output). Class is the same isn't it? When using `diff`, length is one less and we need to `c`oncatenate something useful which is `.5` or `0` (I edited to `0` since it's more logical). With `abs`  we simultaneously cover positive and negative differences.

Comment: thanks. Why does it work on your data frame, but not on mine? Just because of the miliseconds? If I am apllying it on my large dataframe, I am getting same results as with my 'dplyr' approach. Is there an easy way to apply your approach on my data frame or to change my data frame?

Comment: @mcfly Because there was no difference >. 5s.